# Conditional Formatting won't work in excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have inconsistent success with using conditional formatting in excel. I am using this in order to highlight ever other order. The orders are sequential and have multiple lines. The goal is to have a highlight rule that highlights when the "Highlight Rule" column is odd. This column uses the formula =if(C2=C1,C1,C1+1)

[image]

However this doesn't always work. Sometimes it just refuses to highlight anything at all. I have tested to make sure excel sees the cells as even and odd as needed but I am apparently doing something wrong within the rule itself.

[image]

Please help, I feel so dumb that I can't get this to consistently work. I must be doing something different when it works vs when it doesn't but to my eyes I see nothing, it looks exactly the same.

Edit: Added screenshot with rows/columns. The highlight rule would look at column C for alternating highlights.

[image]

Edit 2:

Here is a redacted exact screenshot of my spreadsheet. You can still see column AO reflects the highlighting on the entire sheet:

[image]

**FINAL EDIT Ian below was able to find the obvious thing I didn't think to check. I had a fill overriding my conditional formatting**

Comment: Note: Highlight rule formula should read more like "=if(A2=A1, C1, C1+1)" in line with the screenshot example.

Comment: Trick is to write the formula as if you are in the top-left cell of the range that has the CF rule applied AND to use $ signs just as if you would want to copy that formula to other cells. SO if your range of cells with CFstarts on row 3, then row 3 is the anchor row on which you should base your cell references.

Comment: @jkpieterse thank you! Unfortunately this solution/error only causes the highlight rule to be off by a few lines. The problem is that it highlights nothing at all.

Comment: @ian0411 Added! Thank you! I suppose I should have included those in the first place.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you give an example of some actual values for which it does not work as expected?

Comment: @Minh The format is just a blue highlight instead of yellow. Also yes, I wish I had just forgotten to hit apply. I have remade this rule, adjusted it, applied it, deleted and remade it. Sometimes I just can't get it to work. The screenshot is just me trying to gather the visual of what my setup looks like after I got frustrated so that's probably why "apply" was still active.

Comment: @BenI. the numbers that are relevant are the "count" in the highlight rule. The frustrating part is that I did up a 5 line example and no joke it is working right now (In the example sheet not the real one)

Comment: @Mel, is this what you are trying to do (i.stack.imgur.com/9lurV.png)? This is based on the condition on column AO and therefore the formula in the conditional formatting is =ISODD($AO2). Note the highlighted color just picked randomly for testing purpose.

Comment: @ian0411 Yes except when I do that in this document I get no highlights. If I create a new document it does just fine but this particular document just doesn't work consistently. I even tried copy and pasting as text to get rid of the formula and have done an isodd check next to AO to see if it is indeed registering even/odd numbers (it is).

Comment: Under `Home > Font > Theme Colors (the one with paint icon)`, click the drop down and pick `No Fill`.  I am guessing you have that override your conditional formatting.

Comment: And also, are you trying to format every other row or does this have to be based on a condition from another column?

Comment: If you copy the content of your sheet and paste special formulas to a freshly inserted one, does it work on the new sheet?

Comment: @jkpieterse Yes if I copy everything and paste it over to a new workbook or worksheet I'm able to get it to work. It's as if there's a formatting thing on that particular tab that is stopping it from working.

Comment: @ian0411 the obvious it is! Thank you so much! This has been driving up a wall for months.

Comment: Odd, because conditional formatting overrrides the "current" formatting of the cell.

Comment: @jkpieterse yeah that's usually my experience as well. It's definitely odd that it flips on me... 

Conditional formatting does usually override so I'm not sure what changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in your formatting. You haven't specified that the format is highlight (e.g., yellow). I'm defining my formatting as below, and it works for me.
[image: Format]

I notice that the Apply button is still enabled in your screenshot. Have you actually applied this rule?

Update: also try making the criteria field a range, i.e., =ISODD($AO1:$AO1000)

Comment: this is definitely not the solution unfortunately. I commented above but not sure if it tagged you. 

The format is just a blue highlight instead of yellow. Also yes, I wish I had just forgotten to hit apply. I have remade this rule, adjusted it, applied it, deleted and remade it. Sometimes I just can't get it to work. The screenshot is just me trying to gather the visual for you of what my setup looks like after I got frustrated so that's probably why "apply" was still active.

Comment: Note on this solution for visibility. I have an exact screenshot added at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Is AO your Highlight Rule column? Or is it C?

Comment: AO is in my original document. C is for my simple sample I mocked up.

Comment: Does it work if you highlight the area you want the rule to apply, click "Conditional Formatting", choose the condition, then hit "Apply"?

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't.